# Can't see DataView in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm creating a DataView in in Sencha Touch that exists in one of my Tabs.

The problem is, I can't see my DataView. If I right click -> Inspect Element (in Chrome), I can see the HTML of my DataView on the page (in the Developer Tools), but on the page itself, all I see is a white background.

Here's the source code to my DataView:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.DashboardTab', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'dashboard',

config: {
    title: 'Dashboard',
    itemId: 'dashboardTab',
    layout: 'vbox',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'dataview',
        store: { xtype: 'mystore' },
        itemTpl: [
            '<div class="myDiv">',
                '<table class="myTable">',
                    '<tr>',
                        '<td>Data 0:</td><td>{data_0}</td>',
                        '<td>Data 1:</td><td>{data_1}</td>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '<tr>',
                        '<td>Data 2:</td><td>{data_2}</td>',
                        '<td>Data 3:</td><td>{data_3}</td>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '<tr>',
                        '<td>Data 4:</td><td>{data_4}</td>',
                        '<td>Data 5:</td><td>{data_5}</td>',
                    '</tr>',
                '</table>',
                '<div class="myOtherDiv">',
                    '<img src="{image}" />',
                '</div>',
            '</div>'
        ]
    }]
}
});
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the layout to `fit`?

Comment: This was the problem. I changed my layout to fit and I can now see the DataView. Thanks jprofitt.

Comment: A caution with using `fit` layout is that it will take the first non-docked item and make it the size of the screen. So if you have multiple `items` that aren't docked, you'll need to use a `vbox` or use a `container` around the extra `items`. Otherwise, you'll only see the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your dataview is not getting the data from the store and that is the reason dataview is not getting displayed.

One alternative is to use setData inside your controller to set the data for your dataview.

For an example,

```
var responseObj = serverController.getWSResponse;
   var myDataView = Ext.getCmp('myDataView ');
        var data = myDataView .getData();
        if (data != null) {
            myDataView .onStoreClear();
        }

        myDataView.setData(Ext.JSON.decode('[' + JSON.stringify(responseObj) + ']'));
```

This will give you more flexibility to debug on what you are feeding in the dataview.

Hope this helps.